# Is Elizabethan collar likely to cause very melancholic mourning or should I suspect of something else?

Tags: dogs, behavior

My dog is mourning like never before, this is compeltely new behavior (he is 16 monsths old shiba). Not much, like once a day, while lying down, he cries like a weak howling, at low volume, without opening his mouth. It sounds very, very melancholic.

He's been wearing an Elizabethan collar lately, and I think he's probably stressed and sorrowful because of it. Do you agree with that or do you think I should suspect of other cause? That's the question.

Sorry if this sounds silly, but this is our first pet, and sometimes it is hard to know what to do. Thank you.

[image: Elizabethan collar]

[Image source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Kelpie_wearing_an_Elizabethan_collar.jpg) as used on the [wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabethan_collar)

Comment: What does he have the collar on for? I'm not as familiar with dogs or how this affects them, but I know with my cat, he had a hard time getting food out of his bowl and couldn't lay down on his own properly. It's possible this is hindering too much of your dog's activities, and he doesn't know what to do about it. Hopefully, he doesn't need it for too much longer.

Comment: Could you add an image of what an Elizabethan collar looks like?

Comment: @Flummox I'm under the assumption they mean one of those clear cones they put on dogs and cats to keep themselves from chewing at wounds or stitches. Also known as "the cone of shame". But as it turns out, Elizabethan Collar is actually one of the correct terms for it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabethan_collar

Comment: Call your vet. I'm assuming the dog is wearing the collar due to some sort of medical procedure.  It could be making noise due to discomfort from that procedure.

Comment: Wearing a cone of shame is always an annoyance for dogs, on top of the medical condition he's in, that made the cone necessary in the first place. This might cause the behavior but he has to live through it, bad as it is. However it makes me suspicious that it happens only once a day, as you said, while the collar is on all the time. Since Shibas are very close to their wolf ancestors, it might also be a normal howl or rather the attempt to howl. Wait until the collar is of and see if it still happening and don't assume to much human emotion into the howls, dogs mostly aren't that complex.